# use @ContributesAndroidInjector based on (API level) condition

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have a `ServiceBinderModule` in my Android app that is responsible for adding all my `Service`s to the DI graph like this:

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector
@ServiceScope
internal abstract fun myAutofillService(): MyAutofillService
```

My problem is that I have a Service that extends `android.service.autofill.AutofillService` which is only available from `Android O`. On devices below that API level I have a different solution in place, but since I have `MyAutofillService` on the graph already, the app is crashing at startup (`MyAutofillService` already being in `DaggerAppComponent` but `AutofillService` not being present in the Android framework).

I saw this thread about this topic: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1064

It suggests to use `dagger.android.experimentalUseStringKeys` and `@RequiresApi`, but it has a warning: `Keep in mind that enabling this also breaks incremental annotation processor support on Dagger 5.+`, which I think is a dealbreaker. I'm also not comfortable putting `experimental...` stuff into a production app.

Any advice what I could do? I'd like to put `MyAutofillService` on the graph based on the device's API level.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `experimentalUseStringKeys`, an option I like in that thread is to [make a subcomponent for the higher API level](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1064#issuecomment-364363323).  This subcomponent only needs to contain the `MyAutofillService` binding.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Subcomponent(modules = [MyApi26Module::class])
interface MyApi26Subcomponent : AndroidInjector<MyApplication>

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Module
abstract class MyApi26Module {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    @ServiceScope
    internal abstract fun myAutofillService(): MyAutofillService
}
```

When you create your main component, you can check your `SDK_INT` to decide whether to install it directly or create `MyApi26Subcomponent` and install that instead.

Comment: For people like me :D
From link to GitHub issue https://github.com/TonyTangAndroid/DaggerTutorial/pull/10/files
Check diff and add the same code to your app